# Update multiple records mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Guys my code is below.

What I'm trying to do is to update all of the value in mysql that satisfy a specific a specific condition. Now when I just type in the mysql query:

```
UPDATE `$DBNAME`.`video` SET `Secret_key` = '0'
```

The query works fine but I can't seem to write php code that will do this.
Any help is welcomed

```
    <?php
    // Part 1 (works fine)
    include("/home3/kintest2/public_html/include/config.local.php");
    $connect= mysql_connect ($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPASSWORD);
    $select= mysql_select_db($DBNAME, $connect);
    // End of Part 1

    // Part 2 (works fine)
    $test2= "SELECT * FROM `video`";
    $results= mysql_query($test2, $connect);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($results);
    // End of part 2

    // Part 3 ( Not too sure about this part)
    for ($num_rows= $count; $count >= 0; $count--)
    {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `$DBNAME`.`video` SET `Secret_key` = '0'",$connect);
    }
    // End of part 3 ( Not too sure about this part)


    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
        // Part 1 (works fine)
        include("/home3/kintest2/public_html/include/config.local.php");
        $connect= mysql_connect ($DBHOST,$DBUSER,$DBPASSWORD);
        $select= mysql_select_db($DBNAME, $connect);
        // End of Part 1

        //no need of part 2 to update records in table
        //part 3 loop removed
        mysql_query("UPDATE `$DBNAME`.`video` SET `Secret_key` = '0' ",$connect);


?>
```

Try this. May it will solve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I'd take the query out of the loop (and just delete the loop). If it still doesn't work, try hard coding the database name. If that doesn't work, make sure `$connect` is what you think it is. Look up `mysql_query()` and make sure you're using it right.

If you try everything above, you'll either find the problem or at least figure out what the problem is not.

Comment: Oh, and try deleting ALL your code except the connection and the UPDATE query in question. Kill as many moving parts as possible.

Comment: Thanks Jason Swett. I have tried exactly what you said that's why I named them in parts. Because every part was tested (excluding the loop). Do you know of a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're asking. I don't know what you mean by "this".